# Possible to invoke system's USB mode activity from within an application?

Tags: android, android-activity, usb, mount

Normally a user would have to go to the notification bar -> click "Select to copy files to/from your computer" and then be presented with the activity offering mount/unmount/etc. options. Can anyone share their experience trying to open this from an application?

It appears one guy found a way to open this from within an application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722575/how-to-set-the-usb-connection-mode), but only for an HTC phone. Any idea how I could find out what that activity might be for other devices as well?

**EDIT:** See Comments below; it appears it may be device independent, and the full name of the class is com.android.server.status.UsbStorageActivity

Comment: This is also relevant: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg27542.html - Indicates that the activity I'm looking for is not part of an application that other applications can access... still, might there be some recourse?

Comment: I found the name of the activity - UsbStorageActivity, and here's its implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/server/status/UsbStorageActivity.java

Comment: I found that activity name by watching log cat. It seems device independent. I'm not sure what permissions it might require, and I haven't found anyone else yet with an example of an Intent to launch it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears only the system can open this dialog.

I attempted to launch UsbStorageActivity with

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("android", "com.android.server.status.UsbStorageActivity");
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

But got the following exception:

```
03-21 09:13:55.653: WARN/ActivityManager(2491): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=1000
03-21 09:13:55.653: WARN/ActivityManager(2491): Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=android/com.android.server.status.UsbStorageActivity } from ProcessRecord{47d615c8 3399:com.saltillo.chatpc/10080} (pid=3399, uid=10080) requires null
03-21 09:13:55.657: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3399): Shutting down VM
03-21 09:13:55.657: WARN/dalvikvm(3399): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
03-21 09:13:55.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 09:13:55.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3399): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=android/com.android.server.status.UsbStorageActivity } from ProcessRecord{47d615c8 3399:com.saltillo.chatpc/10080} (pid=3399, uid=10080) requires null
```

Which I interpret to mean this process cannot be launched without sharing [the system uid](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android_uids_and_guids). Which as far as I know is impossible. Otherwise, someone please correct me!